# filter kind of functionality in Ember

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

Does Ember have filter kind of functionality ?

I want to filter the following like it is done in DOJO below;

```
var goodData = dojo.filter(overallData, function(individualData) {
    return !dojo.some(rejectedIds, function(rejId) {
        return rejId == individualData.Id;
    });
});
```

Comment: Did it work for you or ?!

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.

```
var goodData = overallData.filter(function(singleton) {
    return !rejectIds.any(function(rejId) {
        return rejId == singleton.Id;
    });
});
```

For more methods :

*http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html*